# Django Sending HTML Email with Images

Tags: html, django, email, templates, static

I am trying to send an HTML email with images from django 1.3 but my Images are not loading. Following is my view.py

```
email_data = {
# Summary data
'user_name':user_name,
'points':user.numOfPoints,
}
email_data = RequestContext(request, email_data)
t = get_template('user_email.html')
content = t.render(email_data)
msg = EmailMessage(subject='User Email', content, 'admin@company.com', ['user@gmail.com'])
msg.content_subtype = "html"
msg.send()
```

My template('user_email.html') looks like following

```
<html>
<body>
Hello {{user_name}},
Your point score is: {{points}}
Thank you for using our app.
<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/footer.jpg" alt="" />
<body>
</html>
```

The image is place inside the static/image folder of my app folder. But when email is received it is without the image.

In my settings.py, I have following

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
)
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Kindly respond what I am missing?

Thanks,

Comment: What is the rendered url of image in the mail?

Comment: The url of rendered image is 
http://static/images/footer.jpg

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned by roam you are missing the hostname+port.

For those who are using Django's allauth package for authentication (https://www.djangopackages.com/packages/p/django-allauth/), you can simply use {{site}}, e.g.:

```
<img src="{{site}}{{ STATIC_URL }}images/footer.jpg" alt="" />
```

Or better yet, using the %static annotation:

```
{% load static %}
...
<img src="{{site}}{% static 'images/footer.jpg' %}" alt="" />
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to specify the full `STATIC_URL`, e.g `http://localhost:8000/static/`. Right now the message points to `/static/images/footer.jpg` which is not a valid URL.